# Multiple chained API calls to fetch data, but doOnNext of PublishSubject is never reached

Tags: retrofit, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java3

I have a problem to understand a chained "RXJava-Retrofit" API call. I got inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37212173/repeat-request-by-retrofit-and-rx) and implement this class named `ObservationLoader` to load the data from the API bucket per bucket. When the end of data is reached the API sends a `endOfRecords=true`:

```
public Observable<PageObject<Observation>> getAllObservationDataByRegion(long taxonKey,
                                                                         String regionId) {
    final PublishSubject<PageObject<Observation>> subject = PublishSubject.create();
    return subject.doOnSubscribe(disposable -> {
                this.getData(taxonKey, regionId, 0).subscribe(subject);
            })
            .doOnNext(observationPageObject -> {
                if (observationPageObject.isEndOfRecords()) {
                    // -> list is completely loaded
                    subject.onComplete();
                } else {
                    int nextOffset = observationPageObject.getOffset() + 1;
                    this.getData(taxonKey, regionId, null, nextOffset).subscribe(subject);
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}

private Observable<PageObject<Observation>> getData(long id,
                                                    String regionId,
                                                    int offset) {
    // Get your API response value
    return this.api.getObservations(id, regionId, ObservationLoader.PAGE_LIMIT, offset);
}
```

In my Android fragment `HomeFragment` I subscribe to the `ObservationLoader`:

```
ObservationLoader loader = new ObservationLoader(this.getApi());
Observable<PageObject<Observation>> observable = loader
    .getAllObservationDataByRegion(this.getSelectedSpecies(), this.getSelectedRegion());
observable.subscribe(new Observer<PageObject<Observation>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        Log.i(TAG, "ON_SUBSCRIBE");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(PageObject<Observation> observationPageObject) {
        Log.i(TAG, "ON_NEXT");
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "ERROR = " + e.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        Log.i(TAG, "COMPLETED");
    }
});
```

I can see that the `onSubscribe()` and `doOnSubscribe()` are called and even the `getData()` is reached. I assume the API is responding correctly (a previous attempt attempt with recursion worked fine). But I never reached the `doOnNext` function. The observer goes straight to `onComplete()` and no data is received. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `doOnSubscribe` runs, the doesn't see any consumers yet so if `getData` is synchronous, there won't be any first results to trigger further results. Also if `getData` ends, it will complete the setup so the next `getData` call in `doOnNext` will push to an already terminated subject, ingoring all data.

You'll need a differently organized feedback loop:

```java
// we loop back the nextOffset, in a thread-safe manner
Subject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.<Integer>create()
                                         .toSerialized();

// bootstrap with 0 and keep open for more offsets
subject.mergeWith(Observable.just(0))
// get the data for the current offset
.concatMap(nextOffset -> getData(taxonKey, regionId, nextOffset)
                         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
)
// if the response is end of records, stop
.takeWhile(observationPageObject -> !observationPageObject.isEndOfRecords())
// otherwise not end of records, feedback the new offset
.doOnNext(observationPageObject -> 
                         subject.onNext(observationPageObject.getOffset() + 1)
)
// get the data on the main thread
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Comment: This looks promising! I had to change some lines. For example Subject<Integer> needs to be a Subject<Object> with a cast on to Integer on nextOffset. In addition "observationPageObject.getOffset() + 1" needs to be "observationPageObject.getOffset() + PAGE_LIMIT + 1".

After that it loads 1.500 objects out of 1.511 objects. To the last data package is missing. And for results smaller the PAGE_LIMIT nothing returns.

Comment: The subject was a typo, fixed. Do you get isEndOfRecords the same time you get that last 11? If so try `.takeUntil((Predicate<PageObject<Observation>>)o -> o.isEndOfRecords())`.

Comment: I got the things working together. Another problem was a limitations in the REST API: PAGE_LIMIT seems to be unbounded, but the maximum was 300.